# Wordpress child theme - functions.php copy - cannot "redeclare"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Starkers with a child theme (starkers-child).

I need to edit the functions.php to declare a menu, so I copied down the functions.php, JS folder and external folder (which were all declared somewhere in the functions file)

However I still have one error:

```
 Cannot redeclare starkers_script_enqueuer() 
(previously declared in C:\wamp\www\redlaw\wp-content\themes\starkers-child\functions.php:65) in 
C:\wamp\www\redlaw\wp-content\themes\starkers-master\functions.php
```

I believe it is caused by this line:

```
function starkers_script_enqueuer() {
```

I can see why as it already calls the function in the master, so it cannot call it again in the child.

But if I remove this line from the master then doesn't that defeat the purpose of keeping a clean master and having a child theme?

Full functions.php is here (unedited, as it appears in the master theme)
http://jsfiddle.net/8KGcK/

Comment: If you're including/requiring the file, try to include/require once.

Comment: The only other reference to this file is: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starkers_script_enqueuer' );

Comment: I think the standard WordPress workaround is to put all your function declarations inside `function_exists()` calls, so they can be over-ridden by child themes.

Comment: @andrewsi I've added the functions file to my OP. Could you advise regarding this workaround?

Comment: If you need to redefine the functions, you need to wrap the ones in the master functions.php file in calls to `if (! function_exists())` to avoid the error you're getting. However, from your question, it looks like you just need to add in new functions - in which case, you do not need the code from the existing functions.php. You can just start with a new file, and the master theme's functions.php will also work.

Comment: @andrewsi to wrap the ones in the master functions.php file means that when you update the master theme you must redo the modifies in the file, and as said by Francesca that defeats the purposte ok keep clean the master.

Comment: The solution is provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254629/1399205

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override a Wordpress parent theme function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254200/override-a-wordpress-parent-theme-function)

Comment: @AdrianoG.V.Esposito I think you can apply the solution from your link (stackoverflow.com/a/30254629/1399205) only if the function is hooked. If it is a normal function, then it is still a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me, I don't have enough rep to just comment.

A child theme's functions.php is loaded in addition to the parent theme. So you don't need to actually copy and paste the code. What everyone else says about wrapping it in an `if(function_exists(function))` is optional, but a best practice because it's less error prone.

Anyways!

This is from the Codex:

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

[Read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php)