# Override a Wordpress parent theme function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a child theme of flowmaster theme.I have a problem to override the parent function.
The function exists in parent's theme:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'pt_loop_shop_columns');
function pt_loop_shop_columns(){
    if ( 'layout-one-col' == pt_show_layout() ) return 4;
    else return 3;
}
```

I add a function in child theme

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pt_loop_shop_columns' ) ) :
function pt_loop_shop_columns(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ( 'layout-one-col' == pt_show_layout() ) return 4;
    else return 4;
}
endif;
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'pt_loop_shop_columns');
```

Got this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare pt_loop_shop_columns() (previously
>   declared in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\futuratab\wp-content\themes\flowmaster-child\functions.php:44)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\futuratab\wp-content\themes\flowmaster\woofunctions.php
>   on line 9

Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function of child theme is executed first and then parent theme's. Checking using `function_exists` should have been done in parent theme.

To overcome this you can remove parent theme's hook and hook your custom function to same filter.

```
remove_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'pt_loop_shop_columns');

add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'custom_pt_loop_shop_columns');

function custom_pt_loop_shop_columns(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ( 'layout-one-col' == pt_show_layout() ) return 4;
    else return 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.function_exists is not added in parent theme.Add this code in child theme function the error gone.But its not returning 4 item in row.Its still 3 item in row.

Comment: Then try lowering the priority, `add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'custom_pt_loop_shop_columns', 20);`

Comment: Why 20 ??Its working with 20.Can i add any other number tried bellow 11 but not working above 11 is working.

Comment: Default priority is `10`. You can assign number greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redefine a function in PHP, but you can unhook the old function and hook the new one with a different name. Something like:

```
remove_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'pt_loop_shop_columns');
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'pt_loop_shop_columns_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on your child theme

```
function pt_loop_shop_columns() {

//NEW CODE IN HERE///////////////////////////////

return apply_filters('pt_loop_shop_columns', $link, $id);
}

add_filter('attachment_link', 'pt_loop_shop_columns');
```

**OR**

you can use hook on existing function

```
function pt_loop_shop_columns() {
//code goes here
}

$hook = 'get_options'; // the function name you're filtering
add_filter( $hook, 'pt_loop_shop_columns' );
```

**OR**

And last method is

```
 function remove_thematic_actions() {
remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_blogtitle',3);
}
// Call 'remove_thematic_actions' during WP initialization
add_action('init','remove_thematic_actions');

// Add our custom function to the 'thematic_header' phase
add_action('thematic_header','fancy_theme_blogtitle', 3);
```